# Angular ng-click function not being entered when called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on some Angular tabs contained in buttons. For some reason the select function isn't being called when they're pressed. So I think the issue has to be in the html. I provided both sets of code where the issue could be.

Html code

```
<ul>
            <li class="navigation-button" role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isSelected(1)}">
                <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="select(1)" aria-controls="home" role="tab">Home</button>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-button" role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isSelected(2)}">
                <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="select(2)" aria-controls="savings options" role="tab">Savings Options</button>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-button" role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isSelected(3)}">
                <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="select(3)" aria-controls="checking option" role="tab">Checking Options</button>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-button" role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isSelected(4)}">
                <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="select(4)" aria-controls="credit cards" role="tab">Credit Cards</button>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-button" role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isSelected(5)}">
                <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="select(5)" aria-controls="loans" role="tab">Loans</button>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-button" role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isSelected(6)}">
                <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="select(6)" aria-controls="sign in" role="tab">Sign In</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

angular function

```
 $scope.select = function(setTab) {
            $scope.tab = setTab;
            if (setTab === 2) {
                $scope.filtText = "Savings";
            }
            else if (setTab === 3) {
                $scope.filtText = "Checking";
            }
            else if (setTab === 4) {
                $scope.filtText = "Credit";
            }
            else if (setTab === 5) {
                $scope.filtText = "Loan";
            }
            else if (setTab === 6) {
                $scope.filtText = "Sign";
            }
            else {
                $scope.filtText = "Bank";
            }
        };
```

Comment: try the ng-click with <li> element instead of the button..

Comment: under the correct controller?

Comment: do you mean copy paste it into the li and delete the old one or something different?
<html>
 ng-controller= "navController as navCtrl"
<js>
.controller('navController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already working man

```js
var app = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.select = function(setTab) {
            alert("selected");
            $scope.tab = setTab;
            if (setTab === 2) {
                $scope.filtText = "Savings";
            }
            else if (setTab === 3) {
                $scope.filtText = "Checking";
            }
            else if (setTab === 4) {
                $scope.filtText = "Credit";
            }
            else if (setTab === 5) {
                $scope.filtText = "Loan";
            }
            else if (setTab === 6) {
                $scope.filtText = "Sign";
            }
            else {
                $scope.filtText = "Bank";
            }
        };
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <ul>
            <li class="navigation-button" role="presentation" ng-class="{'active':tab == 1}">
                <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="select(1)" aria-controls="home" role="tab">Home</button>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-button" role="presentation" ng-class="{'active':tab == 2}">
                <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="select(2)" aria-controls="savings options" role="tab">Savings Options</button>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-button" role="presentation" ng-class="{'active':tab == 3}">
                <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="select(3)" aria-controls="checking option" role="tab">Checking Options</button>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-button" role="presentation" ng-class="{'active':tab == 4}">
                <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="select(4)" aria-controls="credit cards" role="tab">Credit Cards</button>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-button" role="presentation" ng-class="{'active':tab == 5}">
                <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="select(5)" aria-controls="loans" role="tab">Loans</button>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-button" role="presentation" ng-class="{'active':tab == 6}">
                <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="select(6)" aria-controls="sign in" role="tab">Sign In</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The buttons are activating, but I don't think the select function is being entered

Comment: I stand corrected. I'll figure out how to implement this, thank you!

Comment: would you mind looking at this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/hra04ctr/1/
I can't seem to get it to change even though filtText changes.

Comment: I need the filter to properly filter so that for each tab the correct info displays. Currently whatever the base case is stays. I'm not sure if maybe the function is being entered after the filter has already been applied, of course the wouldn't make sense because then it would just appear one behind on the next click.